# Is it necessary to mark virtual methods as final in a final class?

Tags: c++, c++14, final, virtual-functions

I'm working with C++14, and have a question regarding the use of the `final` specifier. If I declare a class as `final`, does this implicitly mean that all virtual methods within this class are also considered `final`? In other words, is it redundant to mark virtual methods as `final` in a class that's already marked as `final`?

Here's a basic example for clarification:

```
class MyClass
{
    virtual void myMethod() {}
};

class ExampleClass final : public MyClass {
public:
     void myMethod() final; // Is this 'final' redundant?
};
```

In this example, `ExampleClass` is a `final` class. My question is whether the `final` specifier for `myMethod()` is redundant, or if it has any specific effect.

I would appreciate any insights or references to the official C++ standard that clarify this.

Comment: `Is this 'final' redundant?` Yes, it is. If it's not final, how would you override the method after the final class?